# woocommerce image product add a class and data-src attributes

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images, performance

I'm trying to add a class lazyload and the data-src attribute to my product images (woocommerce). I've look everywhere and couldn't find a solution for this.

I've try with some plugins, like a3 lazyload, but it does not work with the product images.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a theme that has WooCommerce support? Look for:

```
woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail
```

and replace it with

```
the_post_thumbnail
```

This has worked before for me with A3 Lazy Load plugin.